# How to upgrade dpkg to python 3.8

Tags: 16.04, python, dpkg

I have Ubuntu 16.04. Recently I upgraded python from 3.5 to 3.8. Now, whenever I try to install something, using apt, I get the following error:

```
Setting up python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.5.postinst: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.5.postinst: /usr/bin/python3.5: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.5 (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5 is not configured yet.
   ...
```

Is there a way to tell dpkg to use Python 3.8 instead of 3.5?

EDIT: I tried to reinstall python3.5 using dpkg but it failed:

```
# sudo dpkg -i python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 342998 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) over (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) ...
Setting up python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.5.postinst: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.5.postinst: /usr/bin/python3.5: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5
```

Comment: It's not a question of the *version* of Python 3. It's about dependencies. All the system-essential dependencies (like python3-apt) are set up to use Python 3.5. We generally recommend NOT changing the system-provided version of Python2/3. Instead, ether upgrade to a newer release or Ubuntu (19.10 uses Py 3.7) or use tools like conda or venv to safely use multiple versions of Python 3 simultaneously. Note that Py 3.8 will be in 20.04, but is currently in testing and not supported here.

Comment: @user535733 so what should I do now? I tried to reinstall python 3.5 using `sudo apt install python3.5` but got the same error...

Comment: Correct - you won't be able to install *anything* using apt. Apt is now broken -- it needs Python 3.5. Download the package manually from http://packages.ubuntu.com then use `dpkg` to install it instead of `apt`.

Comment: dpkg failed too - see my edit. It cannot install python3.5 since it does not find python3.5... I tried to trick it by creating a soft link from /usr/bin/python3.5 to python3.8, but it did not work too..

Comment: You must download and install the `python3.5-minimal` package first (using dpkg). -'minimal' is the package that installs the python symlinks. dpkg does NOT handle dependencies for you.

Comment: @user535733 this solved the problem, thanks! I did not know that upgrading python could wreck such a havoc on my system..